# Parameters(integers)

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and i am doing practiceit questions from the internet.I stumbled upon this question and i got stuck.

Write a method called distance that accepts four integer coordinates x1, y1, x2, and y2 as parameters and computes the distance between points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) on the Cartesian plane. 
For example, the call of distance(1, 0, 4, 4) would return 5.0 and the call of distance(10, 2, 3, 5) would return 7.615773105863909.

```
public static int distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
   int d=(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))^0.5;
    return (double)d;

}
```

2 things i will like to clarify.How come when i use ^,they keep giving me an error to say it cannot be applied.Secondly,i try casting double inside one of number in the equation.But it keeps giving me an error too.

Comment: learn more about [Operators in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) Here ^ is having different meaning. Instead you can use `Math.pow()` function

Answer (score 3):

`^` is the binary XOR operator.

Use [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) instead. Or [Math.sqrt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) (better).

You should not cast your result to `int` and then back to `double`. Just use

```
public static double distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int d=(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))^0.5;
```

In java, `^` is the XOR operator. Use `Math.pow()`.

Raising to the power of a half, is the same at square routing, which can be accomplished with `Math.sqrt()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to power use Math.pow() instead of ^ operator. Or Math.sqrt()
2. You cannot cast double, because your method returns **int**. Change it to *public static double*

Comment: I thought ^ is a substitue of Math.pow()?So it is not?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's XOR operator used for bit operations.

Comment: No.i am not suppose to change.I am supposed to use int.So i am stuck:/

Comment: Then just don't cast it into double on return ;)

Comment: But the question wants me to return a double.

Comment: So write: int d=(int)(Math.sqrt(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)); Or if method have to return double, change its modifiers to: public static double and change variable d declartion to: double d = Math.sqrt(x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1);

Comment: Ok,i get it.Thank you so much for helping.(:

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.sqrt()`, it's built-in method in java math.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't return double if your fiction is expecting a int value.
Second you can use `Math.pow()` instead of `^`, in your case you can use `Math.Sqrt()`.
Third if you want a double result you need to cast the int values you are using to double:

```
public static double distance(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){

    double d = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)-(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
    return d;
}
```

Comment: The cast you left is still not necessary, and it's `Math.sqrt()` not `Math.Sqrt()`. Please use an IDE and copy your code from there in order to avoid compiler errors in your answers.